# Transmit data to Raspberry Pi Tx running windows 10

Tags: c#, c++, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

Need help to output a text to Tx of raspberry pi using windows universal app/ cpp/ c#

Please help me to understand how to transmit data to tx (or write text to tx) of raspberry pi running windows 10 core

Comment: Are you asking to communicate over the SERIAL pins, or communicate with the RPi via a networking interface?  Its not very clear.

Comment: I am trying to communicate over the SERIAL pins..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use the on-board serial device on the Raspberry Pi 2 for Universal Apps - it is reserved for lower-level debugging, like device drivers. See [this](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm) and [this](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/Windbg.htm).

However, I can confirm CP2102-based USB-serial adapters, like this one, work properly.  FTDI-based adapters, by far more common in my experience, **can be made** to work, but they require special installation and specific changes to your program's software.  [Jark](https://github.com/Jark) has some great instructions and a sample program available on [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/Jark/FTDISample).

Comment: The instructions from Jark worked perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: As an update, it looks like a more recent build 10556 (in Insider Preview) mentions that there is serial support for RX / TX pins on the RPi2.  I have yet to confirm, but I'm super excited!   http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/ReleaseNotes.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would use an ASP.NET server page running on the PI. Text could be transmitted via http using URL.

Comment: It's easy to write in python with raspberry pi running linux. The data from tx will be connected to zigbee. I don't think the server page would solve this